# Question about sorting algorithm in non-parallel and parallel?

Tags: c++, sorting, parallel-processing, openmp, sequential

I wondering if there are any sorting algorithm in non-parallel. If so where can I find resources regarding it or if possible could anyone provided me with a simple example of a sorting algorithm in non-parallel?
Also, I found the code below which was an answer from Gabriel Garcia on another topic. should this code classify as one kind of sorting algorithm in parallel using OpenMP?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

struct Compare { int val; int index; };
#pragma omp declare reduction(maximum : struct Compare : omp_out = omp_in.val > omp_out.val ? omp_in : omp_out)

void selectionsort(int* arr, int size)
{
for (int i = size - 1; i > 0; --i)
{
    struct Compare max;
    max.val = arr[i];
    max.index = i;
    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(maximum:max)
    for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; --j)
    {
        if (arr[j] > max.val)
        {
            max.val = arr[j];
            max.index = j;
        }
    }
    int tmp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = max.val;
    arr[max.index] = tmp;
}
}

int main()
{
    int x[10] = {8,7,9,1,2,5,4,3,0,6};
    selectionsort(x, 10);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            printf("%d\n", x[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking here? About an implementation, or an algorithm that cannot be parallelized, or something else? Any algorithm can be written without parallelism but might not by design care about being parallelized or not.

Comment: Just an implementation for sorting algorithm in non-parallel

Comment: Then pick basically any algorithm